# display contents from mysql return only one record

Tags: php, mysql

Im using this code to retrieve all records associated with the usertype="user" row from mysql

```
class user{
public function getnews(){
    $sql5 = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE usertype = 'user'";
    $result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql5);
    $data = '';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data = '<article>';
        $data .= '<h3>' . $row['title'] . '</h3>';
        $data .= '<p>' . $row['content'] . '</p>';
        $data .= '<footer>By: ' . $row['whoposted'] . ' / ' . $row['dateposted'] . '</footer>'; 
        $data .= '</article>';
    }
    echo $data;
}
}
```

and then display the records with.

```
$user = new user();

$user->getnews()
```

and the structure of my database is.

```
id, title, content, whoposted, dateposted, usertype.
```

and assume i have one records that have usertype="admin"

```
id=autoincrement, title="this is the title", content="this is the content", dateposted="2015/03/08", usertype="admin"
```

and 5 records that have usertype="user"

```
id=autoincrement, title="this is the title", content="this is the content", dateposted="2015/03/08", usertype="user"
```

now, as you can see from my mysql query, i suppose to get all the records that has usertype="user" and it suppose to display all records except for one record which has usertype="admin" but it only display one record.

anyone has idea whats wrong with my code?

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Concatenation operator(.=) missing first line in while loop `$data = '<article>';` should be `$data .= '<article>';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `$data` outside the loop, you are doing inside the loop and hence inside each loop its getting over-written and you are getting the last value.

```
$data = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data .= '<article>';
        $data .= '<h3>' . $row['title'] . '</h3>';
        $data .= '<p>' . $row['content'] . '</p>';
        $data .= '<footer>By: ' . $row['whoposted'] . ' / ' . $row['dateposted'] . '</footer>'; 
        $data .= '</article>';
    }
```

Comment: still only display one record. :(

Comment: thanks for the answer. I added $data = ""; before while and then move the echo $data; inside the while statement.

Comment: If you hae multiple records then it should display multiple records. Try doing some test by echoing something inside the loop and see if its getting displayed multiple times, also execute the query in mysql and see if there are multiple records.